# Failed to initialize Monitor Thread Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

When i start the eclipse i  get this error **Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection** and when i try to run an application on eclipse i get these errors in console

**Connection with adb was interrupted.
0 attempts have been made to reconnect.
You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.**

I have tried multiple options mentioned in various other threads on stackoverflow including 1. Disabling Teredo interface 2. Turn firewall off

can somebody please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your anti virus blocked your eclipse,just give allow full access to eclipse on your antivirus security settings

Comment: I faced the same problem in my eclipse and I am using k7 total security.Now the problem is solved